# Json2HTML integrating with my webstore for real-time data delivery

Tags: server-side, json2html

I'm running a few webstores with `Prestashop` for the cart, but I have found a really cool service, but trying to figure out, how it can work for me though..

I've want to transform JSON to HTML on my store's backend before it reaches the customer within seconds since this is going to be a real-time update service for my descriptions and such.

I can send anyone that thinks they can help me the script that I have to use to get this data brought down.

Comment: It is easier for us to help if you post the script in your question.

Comment: architecture wise you can convert json to html using https://github.com/moappi/node-json2html  , however if you want the best performance I would highly recommend sending raw json from your server and transforming it on the client using https://github.com/moappi/jquery.json2html .  Either way you can use the same transform both on the server and on the client with json2html